# Redis Store throws 'undefined offset 0 of 2 bytes' using Laravel's tagged cache with prefix

Tags: php, laravel, caching, serialization, redis

We are serving multiple tenants with a laravel application, switching between tenants with: 
`config(['cache.prefix' => $cachePrefix]);`  
`Cache::setPrefix($cachePrefix);`

Then **sometimes** when we call: 
`Cache::tags('TagName')->add($model->getTable(), 1, $this->refreshTime);`

We get this stack trace:

```
ErrorException unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 2 bytes 
    /usr/share/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.php:345 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
    [internal] unserialize
    /usr/share/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.php:345 Illuminate\Cache\RedisStore::unserialize
    /usr/share/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.php:64 Illuminate\Cache\RedisStore::get
    /usr/share/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/TagSet.php:87 Illuminate\Cache\TagSet::tagId
    [internal] array_map
    /usr/share/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/TagSet.php:76 Illuminate\Cache\TagSet::tagIds
    /usr/share/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/TagSet.php:66 Illuminate\Cache\TagSet::getNamespace
    /usr/share/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/TaggedCache.php:102 Illuminate\Cache\TaggedCache::taggedItemKey
    /usr/share/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/TaggedCache.php:91 Illuminate\Cache\TaggedCache::itemKey
    /usr/share/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php:309 Illuminate\Cache\Repository::add
```

after some extra debugging I am finding that most of the time value in redis for key: `"devtenant_cache:tag:ELASTICSEARCH_REFRESH_REQUIRED:key"` is a serialized value.  But sometimes it is not.  Sometimes it is 0 and sometimes it is the string `OK` which causes it to throw.

[image: value of cache being dumped during execution]

Comment: I don't want to fully close this issue yet because we haven't deployed the solution yet.  But this may be duplicate of this issue:  https://github.com/redis/jedis/issues/397

Comment: We have a function that is forking a thread several times and each process continues to use the same Redis connection. So we are planning to try reconnecting to redis in each fork to see if the issue goes away.

Answer (score 1):

We found that the issue is related to forking our php process.  I wrote this test which fails if you remove the call to `Cache::getStore()->getRedis()->purge();`  So we started purging our redis after forks and also on the main thread.  But we are still getting the error when we try to fetch the result.

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function break_redis_cache()
{
    DB::reconnect('main');
    DB::reconnect('tenant');
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
        $pid = pcntl_fork();
        if ($pid) {
            if ($pid < 0) {
                throw new IndexingException('Failed to fork during Elastic indexing.');
            }

            $pids[$pid] = $pid;
        } else {
            DB::reconnect('main');
            DB::reconnect('tenant');
            Cache::getStore()->getRedis()->purge();
            for ($j = 0; $j < 20; ++$j) {
                $sleep = random_int(0, 15);
                usleep($sleep);
                Cache::tags(CacheTags::ELASTICSEARCH_REFRESH_REQUIRED)->add('logs', 1, 60);
            }
            exit();
        }
    }

    while (count($pids) > 0) {
        usleep(300);
        foreach ($pids as $pid) {
            $res = pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status, WNOHANG);
            if ($res === -1 || $res > 0) {
                unset($pids[$pid]);
            }
        }
    }

    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
```